# C programming initialize 2D array dynamically

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers

I'm doing something silly here and I can't put my finger on exactly what:

```
 void init_data(double **data, int dim_x, int dim_y) {

    int i,j,k;

    data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_x);
    for (k = 0; k < dim_y; k++) {
        data[k] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_y);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dim_x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dim_y; j++) {
            data[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
        }
    }
}
```

And in main() I do the following:

```
double **dataA;
int dim = 10; 
init_data(&dataA, dim, dim);
```

But then right after that when I try printing the data the program crashes:

```
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
            printf("%d\n", dataA[i][j]);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I posted my answer, could you please check if it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making a few mistakes in your pointers. You are passing the `&dataA` to `init_data`, so the argument type should be `***double`, instead of `**double`. Also your first `malloc` is initializing an array of pointers, not an array of doubles, so it should be `sizeof(double *) * dim_x`. The code below should work.

```
void init_data(double ***data_ptr, int dim_x, int dim_y) {
  int i,j,k;
  double **data;
  data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * dim_x);
  for (k = 0; k < dim_x; k++) {
      data[k] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_y);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dim_x; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < dim_y; j++) {
          data[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
      }
  }
  *data_ptr = data;
}

void main() {
  double **dataA;
  int dim = 10;
  init_data(&dataA, dim, dim);
  int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
          for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
              printf("%f\n", dataA[i][j]);
}
```

Your first loop should also have the condition `k < dim_x` instead of `k < dim_y`. It doesn't matter in the current case since both dimensions are the same, but would cause issues if they weren't. Finally, you should use `%f` instead of `%d` in your `printf`, as doubles are stored in a different format than integers, and you are likely to get gibberish instead than what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `dataA` from `main` is never being initialized.  The pointer `data` that you pass to `init_data` is immediately overwritten with a pointer returned by `malloc`.

Comment: My idea was to initialize it with that function then operate on it. Or does it not get initiated in time?

Comment: Then you need to do something like `*data = malloc ...`

Answer (score 1):

If I want to allocate memory and initialize a board, I would:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int xSize, ySize;
  int **board;

  xSize = ySize = 5;

  printf("X: %u; Y: %u\n", xSize, ySize);

  board = calloc(xSize, sizeof(int *));
  printf("%p\n", board);
  int **temp = board;

  for (i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
      board[i] = calloc(ySize, sizeof(int));
      printf("%d %p\n", i, board[i]);
    }
  initializeBoard (board, xSize, ySize);
  temp = board;
  for (i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
      free(*temp);
      (temp)++;
    }

  free(board);

  return 0;
}
```

So initiliaze your board, simply do:

```
void
initializeBoard (int **board, int xSize, int ySize)
{
  int x, y;

printf("----\n");
  for (x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
    {
      for (y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
    {
printf("%3d", board[x][y]);
      board[x][y] = 0;
    }
printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In your case, use `double` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the value of dataA in main().

I would change the definition of init_data to return the pointer to the new data.  Something like this:

```
double ** init_data(int dim_x, int dim_y) {
{
int i,j,k;

double **data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_x);
for (k = 0; k < dim_y; k++) {
    data[k] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_y);
}

for (i = 0; i < dim_x; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < dim_y; j++) {
        data[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
    }
}

return data;
}
```

And then in main()

```
double **dataA = init_data(10, 10);

int i,j;
for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
        printf("%d\n", dataA[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You code has several problems, the majority of which could be easily identified by turning your compiler warnings up.

The first problem is that `init_data` expects a `double**` as it's first argument, however you're passing a `double***` *(check your compiler warnings)*. Since `init_data` is initialising memory that it's allocating itself, as opposed to initialising a block of memory that you allocated elsewhere, you could remove that first argument and return a `double**` instead.

You're also allocating an insufficient amount of memory for `data`. What you want is enough memory for `dim_x` amount of `double*`, *not* `double`. You can achieve that also with `sizeof(*data)` (type of `*data` is `double*`) instead of `sizeof(double*)`.

```
data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * dim_x);
```

Since there are `dim_x` `double*`s in data and `dim_y` `double`s in the block of memory pointed to by each of these `double*`s, your first loop should be iterating up to `dim_x`, and your second up to `dim_y`.

Also, casting the result of `malloc` (casting a `void*`) in C is unnecessary. There are answers on this site that will tell you why it's preferred that you don't.

Another problem has to do with the `printf` format specifier. `%d` is for `int`, `%f` is used for `double` (`%lf` when using `scanf`).

Now if you add code to `free` your allocated memory and run your program through something like *valgrind*, you'll see that you're no longer doing anything naughty in memory.

The working code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double** init_data(int dim_x, int dim_y) {
   int i,j,k;
   double **data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * dim_x); /* hoping not NULL */

   for (k = 0; k < dim_x; k++) {
      data[k] = malloc(sizeof(**data) * dim_y);   /* hoping not NULL */
   }

   for (i = 0; i < dim_y; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < dim_y; j++) {
         data[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
      }
   }
   return data;
}

int main(void)
{
   double **dataA;
   int i, j, dim = 10; 
   dataA = init_data(dim, dim);

   for(i=0; i < dim; i++)
      for(j=0; j < dim; j++)
         printf("%f\n", dataA[i][j]);

   for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
      free(dataA[i]);
   free(dataA);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First mistake is you are passing `&dataA` to the function `init_data`, but in the function you are receiving that value as `double **` it should be `double ***`. Becuase you are passing pointer of a variable of type `double **`. So `init_data` function prototype should be as below

```
void init_data(double ***data, int dim_x, int dim_y);
```

Second mistake is in the below statment

```
data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_x);
```

This statment should be like as below

```
*data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * dim_x);
```

Because we have to update the pointer variable `dataA`. So that we will be able to display it in `main` function after control comes out of `init_data` function. And also we are going to store pointer to a double. So it should be `sizeof(double *)`

Update your `init_data` function as below

```
void init_data(double ***data, int dim_x, int dim_y) 

{      
    int i,j,k;
    *data = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * dim_x);
    for (k = 0; k < dim_y; k++) 
    {         
        ((*data) + k) = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * dim_y);     
    }      

    for (i = 0; i < dim_x; i++) 
    {         
        for (j = 0; j < dim_y; j++) 
        {             
            (((*data) +i) +j) = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);         
        }     
    } 
}
```